# Twitter bootstrap v3x not showing checkbox correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello brothers and sisters.
I have a little problem with twitter bootstrap checkboxes, mainly when rendered in opera, chrome an ie.
Here it is:
I have this piece of code

```
<div class="form-group">
                                <asp:Label ID="LblItemAnulado" Text="Item Anulado" runat="server"  CssClass="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 control-label" />
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <input type="checkbox" aria-label="...">
                                        </span>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

This html code renders fine in firefox, that is, the checkbox control appears correctly; however, in chrome, opera and ie it does not.

checkbox displayed OK (FIREFOX)
[image]

checkbox displayed NOT OK (CHROME, OPERA AND IE)
[image]

If i can't find a solution then I will use a dropdownlist with yes/no options. But i would like to know at least why this happens.

Thank you all for your time and help.

Comment: you need to show us a jsfiddle of the code so we can play around with it.

Comment: It working fine in chrome also see this..https://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/xoa0uvze/

Comment: I also don't see the problem in chrome

Comment: [Here's a bootply](http://www.bootply.com/CtCjazTDbI) with the asp:label converted to a `<span>` (that's what an asp label renders). Looks fine in Chrome  42.0.2311.135 m, Opera 12.14, and IE 11

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, but in the end, don't know why chrome and the other where rendering the span with a 0px width, so I ended up doing this (not an elegant solution..but... well..anyway..)

```
                                        <div class="input-group" style="width:100%;">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:40px;">
                                            <input type="checkbox" aria-label="...">
                                        </span>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
                                    </div>
```

So I added a 100% width to the div and a 40px width to the span and now it is being rendered the way it should be.